# how to solve a single-grouping problem in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to practice pivot with the EMP table provided in oracle by selecting job as the column with ename as the values. 
This is the query I've got so far.

> ```
>      select distinct job, count(job) from emp group by job ... (A)
>      -- Result)
>      -- CLERK 4 
>      -- SALESMAN 4
>      -- PRESIDENT 1
>      -- MANAGER 3
>      -- ANALYST 2
>     select t1.ename, t2.ename, t3.ename, t4.ename, t5.ename
>     from
>         (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'CLERK') t1, 
>         (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'SALESMAN') t2, 
>         (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'PRESIDENT') t3, 
>         (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'MANAGER') t4, 
>         (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'ANALYST') t5, 
>         (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 
>         (select job ... (C)
>         from emp 
>         group by job
>         having count(*) = (
>             select max(count(*))
>             from emp 
>             group by job))
>     ) t6 
>     where t6.n = t1.n(+)
>         and t6.n = t2.n(+)
>         and t6.n = t3.n(+)
>         and t6.n = t4.n(+)
>         and t6.n = t5.n(+)
>     order by t6.n;
> ```

```
    output: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function ... (B)
```

But the output is (B) since there are TWO jobs (CLERK, SALESMAN) with both having value of 4 as you can see from (A).

Question)
Is there a way to modify (C) so it would only select one job despite (A), since I only want to create enough columns for all jobs to fit in after pivoting?

Hope I made myself clear.

*** Finished query ***

> ```
>   select t1.ename "Clerk", t2.ename "Salesman", t3.ename "President", t4.ename "Manager", t5.ename "Analyst"
>             from
>                 (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'CLERK') t1, 
>                 (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'SALESMAN') t2, 
>                 (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'PRESIDENT') t3, 
>                 (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'MANAGER') t4, 
>                 (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 'ANALYST') t5, 
>                 (select ename, rank() over (order by ename) as n from emp where job = 
>                     (select job
>                     from
>                         (select *
>                         from (
>                             select job, count(job)
>                             from emp
>                             group by job
>                             order by count(job) desc) 
>                         where rownum = 1))) t6
>                 where t6.n = t1.n(+)
>                 and t6.n = t2.n(+)
>                 and t6.n = t3.n(+)
>                 and t6.n = t4.n(+)
>                 and t6.n = t5.n(+)
>             order by t6.n;
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using oracle 12c or higher, you can use `FETCH` clause as following:

```
select job, count(job) 
  from emp
group by job 
ORDER BY COUNT(JOB) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

If you are on lower version of oracle then you can use `analytical function` as following:

```
Select job, cnt from
(select job, count(job) cnt, row_number() over (order by count(job) desc) as rn
  from emp
 group by job)
Where rn = 1
```

Cheers!!

Comment: your query definitely works but i'm having trouble combining it to the above but I guess that's my job. And I should've specified the version I'm working on. Thanks!